# Define columns to join on while setting up Association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am having trouble establishing associations between two tables.
I have a User and a Wallet model. 
I know it goes like this
`User.hasOne(models.Wallet)` 

It will will join both tables on `User.id` and `Wallet.id`

But don't get How to define association with custom columns.
Say,
User has `rewards_id` which is a foreign key to `wallet.id`

It tried specifying foreingKey and targetKey as beblow.
`User.hasOne(models.Wallet, { targetKey: "rewards_id", foreingKey: "id"})`
But I am getting belfow error.

```
const userDetail  = await User.findOne({
        where: {
            id_code: 5
        },
        include: {
            model: Wallet
        }
    })
```

> Unknown column 'Wallet.UserId' in 'field list'

Can I achive the same using `hasOne`?
When should I use `hasOne` and `belongsTo`?
I also went through docs, but I don't get please someone explain.

Answer (score 0):

If your User has a link field to Wallet and you would like to associate Wallet in User definition then you should use belognsTo insted of hasOne in the User associations:

```
User.belongsTo(models.Wallet, { foreingKey: "rewards_id" })
```